# Applescript MSoft Word open doc

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript

I am trying to simply open a document with Applescript in Microsoft Word, here's my script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    open document "Macintosh HD:test.docx"
end tell
```

But it keeps telling me the object I am trying to access doesn't exist. But the file is there...!!

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

document refers to an open file in applescript

so what you want to do is open the file

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    open file "Macintosh HD:test.docx"
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](http://www.mactipper.com/2008/01/how-to-open-files-using-applescript.html), which I've just tested, you don't need document nor Macintosh HD but include activate

so, it will be:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open "test.docx"
end tell
```

Comment: Got an error saying test.docx doesn't understand the open message. Thanks for the input

Comment: maybe, since MSWord is so special, you might need to put open document.. now, if your default app for docx is MSWord (and it should) you can use Finder instead to do the "opening" and let it handle the  talk with MSWord

Answer (score -2):

It's been several millenia since I've used AppleScript, but aren't you supposed to refer to a file in the HD folder as `":Macintosh HS:test.docx"` (note leading colon)?

Comment: No. Thanks for the input though.